# Can I pass viewdatadictionary(mymodel) into an mvc view? How then to access it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-views

I feel really daft asking this, sure I'm missing something really simple, but I just can't get it to work!

I've created a ViewDataDictionary like this in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        var recipient = new Recipient() { 
            FullName = "John Brown",
            Company = "FP",
            Email = "name@website.com"
        };
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(recipient);

        UserMailer.OnEventBook().Send();

        return View();
}
```

But I can't work out how to access the data in the view.

I've tried:

```
@ViewData["FullName"]

@ViewData.recipient["FulName"]

@ViewData[recipient.FullName]

@Model.FullName

@recipient.FullName
```

...and a number of similar combinations. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

**Update**

I realise I could just pass it through using ViewBag or ViewData["recipient"].  But I'm curious about this way of doing it.

The below is from the [docs for MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide), and the guy who wrote it seems to know his stuff, so I figured it must be a valid way of passing data through.

```
var comment = new Comment {From = me, To = you, Message = "Great Work!"};
ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(comment);
```

**Update 2**

Doh, I got it wrong.

The MvcMailer makes a call to an action within an action, and  I should have been setting the ViewData in the sub action (OnEventBook() in the code above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change your controller code to:

```
var recipient = new Recipient() { 
    FullName = "John Brown",
    Company = "FP",
    Email = "name@website.com"
};
ViewData["Recipient"] = recipient;
```

Then in you view use the following code:

```
@((Recipient)ViewData["Recipient"]).FullName
```

Anyway if you want a to use a specific object to the View use a Strongly-typed view.

**Update**

If you still want to use ViewDataDictionary you should use the following code to access the model in your view:

```
@ViewData.Model.FullName
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Is it possible to do it the other way as well? Just going to update the question with some details.

Comment: `@ViewData.Model.FullName` gives me a runtime binding on null reference exception.  If I add a `@model` directive to the view I get a standard null ref exp.  But I shouldn't need to because it's being passed as ViewData, is that right?

Comment: I've just double checked it and it's working. You'll have to update your question with the Controller and View code.

Comment: Ok will do. Because it's using MvcMailer it's not a regular view call.  If you would be kind as to check there's nothing obviously wrong...

Comment: I just realised what my error was. The action sending the mailer actually calls another action from within.  (I updated the question to show it.) I should have been setting the ViewData inside of the OnEventBook() action instead of the Index() action.  Thanks for your help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

you can transfer the recipient data as "Model" from the controller to the view
CONTROLLERS:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

   var recipient = new Recipient()
   {
       FullName = "John Brown",
       Company = "FP",
       Email = "name@website.com"
   };


 return view(recipient); //return the recipient as obj model
}
```

VIEWS:

```
@model YourNameSpace.YourRecipientModelFolder.Recipient
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Index";
}
<div>Model:</div>
<div>@Model.FullName</div>
<div>@Model.Company</div>
<div>@Model.Email</div>
```

Note: YourNameSpace.YourRecipientModelFolder.Recipient is something like this MyMVC.Models.Recipient

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer. I'm sorry I wasn't so clear in the original version of the question, I'm wondering if the way I posted was valid, and if so how to access it.